# EF Code First migration maxLength being set to 4000 instead of max

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

tl;dr: I have a column that should be `NVARCHAR(MAX)` but scaffolding a migration with `Add-Migration` is giving me a column with max length 4000 in `Up()`. What do I have to do to get this to be `MAX`?

---

Consider the following model:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Memo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

I have two conventions set up in `Context.OnModelCreating`:

- A convention which sets the default maxLength of any string property not otherwise configured to 1024, with the line:

  ```
  Properties<string>().Configure(c => c.HasMaxLength(1024));
  ```
- An attribute-based convention which reads the `DataTypeAttribute` and sets some properties accordingly, namely the column type and length:

  ```
      switch (attribute.DataType)
      {
          case DataType.MultilineText:
              configuration.HasColumnType("nvarchar").IsMaxLength();
              break;
          case DataType.EmailAddress:
              configuration.HasColumnType("nvarchar").HasMaxLength(255);
              break;
      }
  ```

I tested this all before setting up migrations and it worked beautifully, giving me the following table - note that Memo is being created as **`NVARCHAR(MAX)`**:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Foo (
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Memo NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Email NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo] PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Then I enabled migrations and added one, and got the following table definition in `Up()`:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Foo",
    c => new
        {
            Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
            Memo = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 4000),
            Email = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 255),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
```

Wha? Where'd that **`maxLength: 4000`** come from? It's not the `MAX` I would expect, nor is it even the `1024` I configured as the default with my first convention. It's certainly respecting the `100` and `255` of `Name` and `Email` (proving my attribute-based convention is working)...

So, is this a bug in the framework, or is there something about migrations that I'm not understanding? And either way, what can I do to get Code First Migrations to respect my `IsMaxLength()`?

Comment: A SQL Server table can have up to 8K (minus headers) data. Therefore, the variable length string types are limited to **8000 bytes** - that is  a `varchar(8000)` or a `nvarchar(4000)` (2 bytes per character) maximum. Anything beyond that must use the `(max)` datatypes

Comment: @marc_s ok so that explains where the number 4000 comes from, but how can I get my `(max)` back, like it used to be before enabling migrations?

Answer (score 5):

Apparently `IsMaxLength()` *has a different meaning* in the context vs in a migration. In the context, it creates a column of `NVARCHAR(MAX)` but once you enable migrations this is interpreted as "the biggest possible value the column allows, except for MAX". As @marc_s points out in a comment, this is 4000 for a `nvarchar` column.

Indeed, while I have read this works outside of migrations, setting `HasMaxLength(int.MaxValue)` and calling `Add-Migration` gives me the following error:

> (0,0) : error 0026: MaxLength '2147483647' is not valid. Length must be between '1' and '4000' for 'nvarchar' type.

Playing around a little more, I decided to try `HasColumnType("nvarchar(MAX)")`, which to my surprise *worked*! So replacing the call in the convention above works.

I can't find any way to read out the result of `IsMaxLength()` anywhere where I can set the type (for example `IStoreModelConvention` is too late), so it's not the prettiest solution, but at least I can move forward.